# ASP.NET Core - Middleware Reordering in Startup class

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, razor-pages, asp.net-core-middleware

I have used two Map methods one after other in Startup class in a demo ASP.NET Core 5.0 Empty project. I know that Map method is used to branch the middleware pipeline. As per the pathMatch string, Map method is executed. But the problem is second Map method is not executed as per the path string is given in the URL.

I have used the following code in Startup class. The output for https://localhost:44327 is Middleware1 as expected but for https://localhost:44327/test, it returns again Middleware1, not Middleware2. Why? I am not sure why it is so. If I reorder the statements 1and 2, I get as expected i.e. https://localhost:44327 returns Middleware1 and https://localhost:44327/test returns Middleware2. What is flaw in my concept? Thanks in advance for answer.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("", builder => builder.Run(ctx => ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Middleware1"))); // statement 1
            app.Map("/test", builder => builder.Run(ctx => ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Middleware2"))); // statement 2
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

app.Map("") will map any route.

Either reorder so app.Map("") acts as a 'Fallback' when no other route is identified:

```
app.Map("/test", builder => builder.Run(ctx => ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Middleware2"))); 
app.Map("", builder =>
    builder.Run(ctx => ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Middleware1")));
```

Or use MapWhen, where you can use "/" to specifically identify site root path:

```
app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path == "/", builder => builder.Run(ctx => ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Middleware1")));
app.Map("/test", builder => builder.Run(ctx => ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Middleware2")));
```